# Selecting Numbers from a Range of Years

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to execute a SQL query such that the following table:

```
    id         in_year     out_year 
  -------    ----------  -------------
     1          2001        2002 
     2          2002        2002 
     3          2004        2007
```

can be queried such that I get all the years within that range mapped to the id. For instance, I would like to get:

```
    id         year 
 ---------   ---------
     1          2001
     1          2002
     2          2002
     3          2004
     3          2005
     3          2006 
     3          2007
```

Specifically, lets say the table represents a shop with elements and their arrival to shop, and sell dates. The query would return all the element ids mapped to the year where they were in the shop.

Comment: There is no an elegant solution for that (but you may create SP or temporary table with years to join) - the better would be to do that in your app

Comment: I was actually trying to do it by using a temporary table. How do you do the join?

Comment: create a temporary table with numbers `1..42` and join the current table with `ON out_year <= in_year + tmp.n` where `tmp` is a temporary table and `n` is the only column name

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a temp table with the years in your range of data i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_years (
 yr YEAR NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (yr)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO tmp_years (yr) VALUES (2000), (2001), (2002), (2003), (2004), (2005), (2006), (2007);
```

and then do a JOIN:

```
SELECT w.id, y.yr FROM wesams_table w 
INNER JOIN tmp_years y ON (y.yr >= w.in_year AND y.yr <= w.out_year);
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work. I cannot make assumptions about the data or the ranges as it will change dynamically. For instance, what I would want to do is to find the minimum year of intime_years and the maximum of outtime_years, generate a temporary table from that min-max range, and then do the join. You see what I am saying?

Answer (score 0):

The tidiest solution would be to create a UDF to return the range of years and use CROSS APPLY.

Performance should be rather good as the UDF will be deterministic

Edit: Sorry, I don't think this applies to MySQL.